# Seek Advice SQLite or SharedPreferences for a Quiz App

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am developing a quiz app, which will have mostly multiple choice questions. I decided to use prepopulated SqlLite (enbedded with the build) with just one table with the data model like below. I will have around 500 questions to start with.

```
ID | QID | Question_Text | Correct_Answer | Choice1 | Choice2 | Choice3 | Question Type | Difficulty_Level | Category | Image link
```

Should be able to retrieve questions based on difficulty level. There might be new questions added which needs to be downloaded periodically and gets added to the database. There might be modifications to the existing questions too. The app might also be upgraded with new questions in future releases.

Still unable to decide whether Shared Preferences built from JSON file(embedded into the build) will be a better approach performance wise and maintenance wise with updating of the existing questions or with upgrades in future releases.

I read many discussions on this and feel like any approach should work and both have their pros and cons. But wanted to check if some one have faced any issues with any of the above approaches.

Comment: use Sqlite not sharedpreferences

Comment: You should use SQLite database as @Raghunandan suggested!

Comment: Thanks Raghu and Android Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences are designed for Application settings. they abstract the setting-storing process to the developer, but they are not intended to store big amounts of data in a "table style" design. To do that is better to use a SQLite database. It will be easier for you to maintain your application in the future and probably easier to develop since you are able to do more complicated queries directly.

Comment: Thanks Guillermo Merino for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use Sqlite preferences are used for saving settings